# Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 - List personal contacts using application permissions

Tags: rest, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-webapps

I've registered a web application in Azure Portal, granted it a `Contacts.Read` permission, gave it an administrator consent and now trying to list personal contacts of a particular user with Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 using this application.

At first i'm trying to get an access token by sending `POST` request to
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token` with following body parameters: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/contacts.read`, `grant_type=client_credentials`, my `client_id` and my `client_secret`.

In response i'm getting an error `400 Bad Request`. Body:
`{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/contacts.read is not valid."}`

When i'm replacing scope parameter in token request like this: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, i'm actually receiving `200 OK` and my Bearer token in response.

But when i'm requesting user personal contacts by sending `GET` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/contacts` with this token, i'm getting `401 Unauthorized` in response with following error:

`"code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
"message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",`

I've also tried to replace the `scope` value in my token request with `{app_id_uri}/.default` and `{app_id_uri}/contacts.read` with no luck.

So how do i list user personal contacts using Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0? What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Permissions screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Decode the access token in https://jwt.io/ , check if it has the `contacts.read` permission?

Comment: you've set contacts in the legacy exchange try adding the graph contacts permission instead.

Comment: @Dave, you're right. I've already done that. That solved my problem.

Comment: @Dave i can mark your answer as a solution if you post it

Comment: thank you I've added that to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the scope:

> scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

You will need Application permissions (Admin):

- users.read.all
- contacts.read

I'd opt for the readwrite versions in case you want to add/edit contacts

I also use Delegated permission with offline_access

you've set contacts in the legacy exchange add the graph contacts permission instead.

Answer (score 1):

I granted to my application wrong permissions. It was `Contacts.Read` and `User.Read.All` permissions in `Exchange` section instead of `Microsoft Graph` section.

I granted those permissions in `Microsoft Graph` section and everything worked. In fact `Contacts.Read` permission is enough.

P.S. the scope is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`